# Install Windows Universal App 8.1 in Devices(Windows machine 10,8.1)

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

How can windows universal app be installed in windows machine with out submitting in the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sideloading for testing / installing your app on any device without submitting to store.

MS differentiates between *developer sideloading* and *enterprise sideloading* - just choose which method you prefer depending on your needs.

There is an in-depth explanation of the installation process in the MSDN over [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn832613.aspx).